# What is the use of a variable function in PHP?

Tags: php

I understand how to implement a variable function though i don't understand it's use. Why call a function using a variable than to call the function itself?

Unless to dynamically call functions from user input or returned database results?

Comment: I honestly do not use this function but, its just a design concept. You can do essentially the same thing with variable names. Which I will use on occasion. For example I might be trying to create a data structure with an arbitrary number of key/value pairs so I will loop through the set naming each of the variables with a counter ($i). so key_i and Value_i
when I am done i will have variable $key_1..$key_20 and $value_1...$value_20. I am sure there is a use case for dynamically defining functions with a closure maybe. I just have never needed it.

Comment: @ChrisRichardson Thanks mate. I couldn't find anything on SO about it, i guess it's not used a whole lot, only in niche cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXAMPLE : if you have an input like `/?do=something`

```
require_once('do.php');
$fun = 'do_'.$_GET['do'];
if (function_exists($fun)) {
    $fun(); //variable function
} else {
    not_found();
}
```

so in this case I just add a function to my do.php file and it will be ready to use

do.php :

```
<?php
function do_getkey() {
    // do something when do=getkey
}
function do_sendkey() {
    // do something when do=sendkey
}
 function not_found() {
    // when not found 
 }
?>
```

Comment: Make sense, so you can call a function from a GET or POST value as an example.